# Angular 6 - Integrating jQuery/JavaScript files

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular-cli

I am trying to integrate a jQuery plugin into my Angular CLI project. This plugin is **NOT** a node package. It's a Calendar Picker (the files can be found [here](http://bugsvoice.com/applications/bugsVoice/site/test/calendarPickerDemo.jsp))

I have added these files into an assets folder in the 'src' folder of the project and added the paths (styles/scripts) to the angular.json file. Still nothing. I have jQuery installed on this project and have used npm jquery plugins and they work fine.

Can somebody please upload an Angular CLI example, that uses the linked plugin?

The below example just returns the error of 'this.calendarPicker.calendarPicker is not a function'

I would be very grateful for any assistance.

App Component Typescript

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-organiser-area',
      templateUrl: './organiser-area.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./organiser-area.component.css']
    })
    export class OrganiserAreaComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('calendarPicker') picker: ElementRef;
      calendarPicker: any;

      constructor() { }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.calendarPicker = $(this.picker.nativeElement);
        const winWidth = $(window).width();
        if (winWidth > 480) {
          this.calendarPicker.calendarPicker({
            monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            dayNames: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            useWheel: true,
            callbackDelay: 100,
            years: 2,
            months: 3,
            days: 5,
            showDayArrows: true,
            callback: function(cal) {
              $('#selectedDate').html('Selected date: ' + cal.currentDate);
            }
          });
        } else {
          this.calendarPicker.calendarPicker({
            monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            dayNames: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            useWheel: true,
            callbackDelay: 100,
            years: 1,
            months: 3,
            days: 3,
            showDayArrows: true,
            callback: function(cal) {
              $('#selectedDate').html('Selected date: ' + cal.currentDate);
            }
          });
        }
      }

    }
```

App Component HTML

```
<main>
  <div #calendarPicker class="calendarBox"><div id="calendar"></div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.calendarPicker.calendarPicker is not a function

You have this error because your library dont have type definition for angular CLI. The variable calendarPicker is just the variable you decleare so how can you use the library. 
So first you need to install 2 package like this

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Download the library you need and put the file in your assets folder

Then in scripts section in architect => build of angular.json file you need to add path for jquery lib. Please change the path accordingly with your

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ....
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/jquery.calendarPicker.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/jquery.calendarPicker.js"

           ]
          },
```

Then in your tsconfig.app.json add this

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jquery"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Finally change your component file into this

```
  import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-organiser-area",
  templateUrl: "./organiser-area.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./organiser-area.component.css"]
})
export class OrganiserAreaComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("calendarPicker") picker: ElementRef;
  calendarPicker: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.calendarPicker = $(this.picker.nativeElement);
    const winWidth = $(window).width();
    $("#calendar").calendarPicker({
      monthNames: [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
      ],
      dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      useWheel: true,
      callbackDelay: 500,
      years: 1,
      months: 3,
      days: 4,
      showDayArrows: false,
      callback: function(cal) {
        $("#mydate").html(cal.currentDate + "");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Ngo 
Do you think you could upload a live code example of this working?